# Discrete Mathematical Question (When is $P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$ true)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**
Let $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ be propositional variables. When is the statement $P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$ true?

I'm currently learning the basics of discrete math. I am stuck on this last question of my assignment... not really sure how to go about solving it.

I do know that a propositional variable can either be true or false.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the $\bigoplus$ operator is/does?

Comment: The ⨁ operator is pronounced 'Exclusive or'. P⊕ Q is true if P and Q have different values.  “P or Q but not both”.

Comment: Do you know when $P\bigoplus Q$ is True and when False?

Comment: No, the question only states what I put on here, and does not indicate when it's true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: You may think of $\oplus$ as acting like mod $2$ addition by taking $T$ as $1$ and $F$ as $0$. Then 
\begin{align*}
T \oplus F &=1+0=1 \pmod{2}\\
T \oplus T &=1+1=0 \pmod{2}\\
F \oplus F &=0+0=0 \pmod{2}
\end{align*}

Let $k$ be the number of statements that are true among $P_1, P_2, \ldots ,P_n$, so the remaining $n-k$ are false. Then $\oplus_{i=1}^{n}P_i$ is true if and only if $k$ is odd because based on the  idea I have suggested above, we can think  of $\oplus_{i=1}^{n}P_{i}$ as $\underbrace{1+1+\dotsb+1}_{k} \equiv k \pmod{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x \bigoplus {\rm False}$ has the same truth value as $x$.

$x \bigoplus {\rm True}$ has the opposite truth value as $x$.

So every time you have a True among the arguments, the truth value flips.